# How to remove more than 1 fields from one file using unix script

Tags: shell, unix

I have one file which has 2 '-' (hyphen or minus) symbol as fields. It has got 21 fields. I can count the position of those fields and those are $2 and $3. How would I remove such fields using unix shell script. Sample data is given below:

```
192.168.1.223 - - [15/Jul/2015:16:54:07 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 4954 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2453.0 Safari/537.36"
192.168.1.223 - - [15/Jul/2015:16:54:08 +0530] "GET /icons/apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2326 "http://192.168.1.232/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2453.0 Safari/537.36"
```

I want to remove '-' at $2 and $3 position. 
But would like to add a point. These positions I can figure out since it is known to me. What if I do not know positions and no of fields are more. I just want to automate the system so that the code will search it in the line and remove it.

In short I want to write a script which will check each field of the given file and will remove those fields which are kind of junk characters like '-'(hyphen or minus).

Comment: What is a "unix" script? I've heard of awk, but not of unix script.

Comment: any shell script. I have tried with following but not working.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$1

F_CNT= awk '{printf F}' $FILENAME

for i in {0..21}

awk '{if ($i== "-") {$i="";print}  else {print};}' $FILENAME >tmp && mv tmp $FILENAME

done

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your attempts.

Comment: Also, what is your desired output for that inut? Again, you should [edit] your question to show us.

Answer (score 0):

The following works on my (Linux) machine to remove columns 2 and 3:

```
cut -d ' ' --complement -f 2,3
```

I don't know how standard/portable the `--complement` option is.

---

On the other hand, if you want to remove fields consisting of `-` no matter where they appear, try:

```
perl -pe 's/ -(?= )//g'
```

Comment: The answer is ["not very standard"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) :)